# New Signature Field Rotated 90 Degrees

Tags: c#, itext

I’m able to add a new signature block on the PDF using an annotation, but it’s always rotated 90* to the page.  I’ve tried using the .Rotate method on the annotation before adding it, but that does nothing.  I also rotated the PDF template and the added signature field maintains the same relative 90* orientation. I've also changed the rectangle points and that does not appear to have any effect on the rotation. I do NOT want to sign the PDF...I only wish to add a blank sig field for signing by other parties later.

```
//Get location to the field where we will place the signature field
AcroFields.FieldPosition NewPosition = fields.GetFieldPositions("DESC_0_" + (itemno + 1).ToString())[0];
float l1 = NewPosition.position.Left;
float r1 = NewPosition.position.Right;
float t1 = NewPosition.position.Top;
float b1 = NewPosition.position.Bottom;

PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(pdfStamper.Writer);
field.FieldName = "G4_Signature";

// Set the widget properties
field.SetWidget(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(r1, t1, l1, b1), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE);
field.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
// Add the annotation
pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(field, 1);
```

[image: Rotated signature field]

- Link: [Template PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3pKBz-WDrXnM3hYeDFtXzhldnM)
- Link: [Populated PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3pKBz-WDrXnRUR6Y3JOc2V4Zms)

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question?

Comment: I have updated the questions with links to the template PDF and completed PDF with rotated signature field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page in your document is rotated using the **Rotate** page dictionary entry. When creating a field to be filled-in by others later, you have to add a hint to the field indicating a counter-rotation if you want the field content to effectively appear upright.

You do this by setting the `MKRotation` attribute of the field:

```
field.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
// Add a hint for upright signature creation
field.MKRotation = 90;
// Add the annotation
pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(field, 1);
```

This creates a rotation entry **R** with value 90 in the appearance characteristics dictionary **MK** of the field.

For backgrounds:

> **MK** dictionary *(Optional)* An appearance characteristics dictionary (see Table 189) that shall be used in constructing a dynamic appearance stream specifying the annotation’s visual presentation on the page.
>
> The name **MK** for this entry is of historical significance only and has no
>   direct meaning.
>
> *(Table 188 – Additional entries specific to a widget annotation - in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

and

> **R** integer *(Optional)* The number of degrees by which the widget annotation shall be rotated counterclockwise relative to the page. The value shall be a multiple of 90. Default value: 0.
>
> *(Table 189 – Entries in an appearance characteristics dictionary - in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

Comment: I swear I tried this yesterday before I posted....evidently not.  This solves my rotation issue.  Thank you.

Comment: I tried to manually add a `/R` entry in a `/MK` dictionary of a field and this had no effect at all in the visual appearance of a field in an already rotated page (page with `/Rotate` entry). Same for a non rotated page.

Comment: Answering myself, `/MK` make sense only as an hint when constructing an appearance, and don't apply to existing already constructed ones. As written in the PdfReference 1.7, "**MK** dictionary (Optional) An appearance characteristics dictionary (see Table 8.40) to be used **in constructing** a dynamic appearance".